# how to make middle content on top in responsive web design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a 3 div inside a div named is left-content, middle-content, right-content. What i want is that middle-content must come on top and left-content, right-content below middle-content in responsive design. Here is my code:

```
 <div id="content">
    <div id="left-content">
        <p>
            <b>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed
                diam nonummy nibh euismod
                tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna
                aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim
                ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
                exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit
                lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea
                commodo consequat.
            </b>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="middle-content">
        <img src="img/img1.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div id="right-content">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed
                diam nonummy nibh euismod
                tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna
                aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim
                ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
                exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit
                lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea
                commodo consequat.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>


 css code:


   body{
     margin:0;
     padding 0;
    }
    #content{
      width:900px;
      height:auto;
      overflow:hidden;
      margin:0 auto;
       margin-bottom:20px;
    }
    #left-content{
      width:200px;
      height:auto;
       float:left;
    }
    #middle-content{
      width:500px;
       height:auto;
        float:left;
   }
    img{
      width:100%;
       height:auto;
    }
     #right-content{
      width:200px;
      height:auto;
      float:left;
      }
     @media (max-width:480px){
   #content{
    width:90%;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 auto;
  }
  #left-content{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    text-align:justify;
}
#middle-content{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    float:right;
}
 #right-content{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
}
```

}

plz help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use  `display:flex;` and `mediaquerie`.
**[DEMO set at 500px](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ftori)**

```
#content {
  display:flex;
}
 #content>div {
   flex:1;
 }
img {
  width:100%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:500px){
  #content {
    flex-direction:column;
  }
  #content > div {
    order:2;
  }
  #content  #middle-content {
    order:1;
    width:100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://plnkr.co/edit/QfY8pf?p=preview 
I created a separate div for the top-middle-content that was hidden at regular size and visible in the media tag. Resize the preview pane to below 480px to see the effect.

The problem with using things like flex is that only extremely recent browsers can display it. Most browsers would have no idea what it's talking about. (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex Browser compatibility.)

Media itself is only supported since IE 9. So you might want to use a javascript solution instead. I'll post one soon as an edit.

**EDIT:**

You might try something like this:
(Or take a look at [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), if you want a more consistent and reliable solution.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      (
        function($){
          var currentWidth = 0;

          var check = function() {
            var newWidth = window.innerWidth;
            if(currentWidth != newWidth) {
              currentWidth = newWidth;                 
              if(currentWidth < 480) {
                $('#middle-content').empty();
                $('#top-content').html($('#moveable').html());
                $('#left-content, #middle-content, #right-content').removeClass('floatLeft');
              }
              else {
                $('#middle-content').html($('#moveable').html());
                $('#top-content').empty();
                $('#left-content, #middle-content, #right-content').addClass('floatLeft');
              }
            }
          }

          setInterval(check, 300);
        }
      )(jQuery)
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <style>
      .floatLeft {
        float:left;
      }

      #left-content {
        width:auto;
      }
      #middle-content {
        width:auto;
      }
      #right-content {
        width:auto;
      }
      #left-content.floatLeft,
      #right-content.floatLeft {
        width:200px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script type="text/template" id="moveable">
      <div id="moveable-content"><h1>Middle Content</h1></div>
    </script>
    <div id="top-content"></div>
    <div id="left-content">
      <p>
        <b>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
          consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed
          diam nonummy nibh euismod
          tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna
          aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim
          ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
          exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit
          lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea
          commodo consequat.
        </b>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="middle-content"></div>
    <div id="right-content">
      <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex
      ea commodo consequat.
    </p>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, you can use pure CSS, but if < IE9 is a concern, maybe my answer is a start.

Comment: Sorry, I still had the plunker script reference until a few seconds ago.

Answer (score 0):

```
body{
height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

#content{
  position:relative;
  background:#dedede;
height:100vh;
}

#left-content{
border:1px solid red;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
}

#right-content{
border:1px solid green;
position:absolute;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r57UM/1/).

I don't think you can achieve this with pure CSS, given the fact that **middle-content** is, well, in the middle.

You may also want to trigger this if any window resizing occurs.

Comment: using CSS3 `Flex` its possible.

Comment: @jme11 : Great answer, I will take a closer look, and you are right, I wish all of us had more time to do some reverse engineering on popular frameworks like Bootstrap. Surely there is a lot to learn.

Answer (score 0):

A non-flex based, non-javascript, fully css solution **IS** possible.  Here are the parts, the explanation is at the end:

**CSS:**

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding 0;
}
#content{
    width:100%;
    max-width: 900px;
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
#content:after{
    clear: both;
}
#left-content{
    width: 33.33333%;
    float:left;
    left: 33.33333%;
    position: relative;
}
#middle-content{
    width: 33.33333%;
    float:left;
    right: 33.33333%;
    position: relative;
}
img{
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
}
#right-content{
    width: 33.33333%;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
}
@media (max-width:480px){
    #content{
        width:90%;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    #left-content{
        width: 100%;
        text-align:justify;
        left: 0;
    }
    #middle-content{
        width:100%;
        left: 0;
    }
    #right-content{
        width: 100%;
    } 
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="left-content">
        <img src="img/img1.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div id="middle-content">
        <p>
            <b>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed
                diam nonummy nibh euismod
                tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna
                aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim
                ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
                exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit
                lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea
                commodo consequat.
            </b>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="right-content">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed
                diam nonummy nibh euismod
                tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna
                aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim
                ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
                exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit
                lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea
                commodo consequat.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Okay, so as someone else already suggested, if you have a fairly complex design, you probably should consider using a responsive framework like Bootstrap or Foundation (or if you don't all of the goodness these frameworks deliver, you could use just their grid components).  If you don't want to use a framework for whatever reason, you can at least learn from how they do things and one of the things both offer are ways to push/pull grid columns to change the display order.  That's exactly what I did here:

1. I changed your source order to reflect the content as you want it to be on the smallest device size.  So, you'll notice that the image is now in the `left-content` column.
2. I gave your columns a width of 100% on viewports less than 480px with a media-query.  This way, each column will be the full width of the `content` div on those devices.  Change the `max-width` in the media-query to whatever you want it to be.
3. Then, I specified that the columns should be only 33.33333% wide (yes, I used percentages to make it be more fluid, but you can use the same techniques with fixed widths if you prefer) outside the media-query and floated them **ALL** left.
4. By floating them all left, you can use positioning to offset the columns and literally change the display order.  So, I gave each column position relative and on the `left-content` column I set the **left** value to 33.33333%.  This essentially is "pushing" the column left by the same amount as the column width that we want it to occupy.  Then I sent the **right** value for the `middle-content` column to 33.33333%, which "pulls" this column to the left to occupy the space where the other column is.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/3kFSC/) to show how it works.